# Docker Container network host mode works from CLI but not Go SDK

Tags: docker, go

Running Docker 18.09.1, API 1.39, and trying to put a container's network into host mode so Bluetooth works correctly. When I launch my container from the CLI, everything works perfectly:

```
docker run --rm --name mycontainer --net=host imageName my-command
```

When I try to start this container using the Go API, the network seems to not be set correctly, causing my container to die.

```
config := &container.Config{
    Cmd:      []string{"my-command"},
    Hostname: "mycontainer",
    Image:    imageName,
}

hostConfig := &container.HostConfig{
    AutoRemove: true,
    NetworkMode: "host",
}


container, err := cli.ContainerCreate(*ctx, config, hostConfig, nil, "mycontainer")
```

It seems pretty clear that I'm missing *something* but I can't see what that is. Do I need a network config (the `nil` argument to `ContainerCreate`) since I am specifying the network mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I caught my problem as I was about to post the question, so I'll share it since this wasn't explicitly clear in any documentation. When using the `host` network mode, your container config should not have a hostname.

Changing this:

```
config := &container.Config{
    Cmd:      []string{"my-command"},
    Hostname: "mycontainer",
    Image:    imageName,
}
```

...to this:

```
config := &container.Config{
    Cmd:      []string{"my-command"},
    Image:    imageName,
}
```

Was all it took.